# Trying to see the 3D Manipulator Widget on selected objects

Tags: modeling

How do I get the 3d manipulator widget to appear on a selected object in Blender 2.8. When I select any object in the scene the widget does not appear with it. Is there a menu item that makes it appear?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Is the 3D widget active? Does it show the three icons for move, rotate and scale beside it? If not click on it, or press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle it on.

If the widget still doesn't appear on the selected object, it may be that the object's  Origin is somewhere else in the scene. The manipulator will be placed over the origin. If this is the case, go to the Tools tab of the Tools box (press <kbd>T</kbd> if the tools box isn't there). You do this in Object mode. About half way down, click on Set Origin, and then Origin to Geometry.

[Link to Manual's description of the 3D  manipulator widget](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/manipulators.html#transformation-manipulators).

Comment: Hi Susan, welcome to Blender.SE, this is a very useful first answer. Consider [uploading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/404048) a cropped [screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/) with the icons marked. To new user, the interface is confusing and they may not find the icons. Also, link to the manual. I couldn't find anything about the 3D Widget, do you perhaps mean the [Transform Manipulators](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/manipulators.html#transformation-manipulators)?

Comment: Yep, it's called the Transform Manipulator in the manual.

Comment: The link you posted could only be accessed by you, since that version of the manual is on your local hard drive. I replaced it with Leander's link.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for changing the link's URL